# Uncurried functions

Tags: haskell, currying

I'm having trouble understanding curried and uncurried functions. All the sites I Google'd to try to provide me a definition were unclear to me.

In one example I found them saying that

`max 4 5` is the same as `(max 4) 5`

But I don't understand what they're doing. How can you have a function `(max 4)` when max requires 2 parameters? I'm completely lost.

Comment: See also [What is the advantage of currying?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/185585/61231).

Comment: I think this question and my answer there might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148253/how-are-functions-curried/8148957

Answer (score 14):

The trick with Haskell is that functions only take one argument. This seems totally crazy but it actually works.

A haskell function:

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> Int
foo a b = a + b
```

Really means: A function which takes in 1 argument, and then **returns another function which takes one argument**. This is called currying.

So using this, we can really write this function definition like this:

```
foo :: Int -> (Int -> Int) --In math speak: right associative
```

and mean exactly the same thing.

This is actually super useful because we can now write concise code like:

```
foo1 :: Int -> Int
foo1 = foo 1
```

Since function application in haskell is just whitespace, most of the time you can just pretend that curried functions are uncurried (taking more than one argument and just returning a result).

If you really really realllly need uncurried functions: Use tuples.

```
uncFoo :: (Int, Int) -> Int
uncFoo (a, b) = a + b
```

**Edit**

OK so to understand whats going on with partial application consider `bar`

```
bar a b c = [a, b, c]
```

The thing is, the compiler will desugar what you just typed into lambdas like this

```
bar = \a ->
      \b ->
      \c ->
           [a, b, c]
```

This takes advantage of closures (each inner function can 'remember' the arguments to the previous ones.

so when we say `bar 1`, the compiler goes and looks at `bar` and sees the outermost lambda, and applies it giving

```
bar 1 = \b ->
        \c ->
             [1, b, c]
```

If we say `bar 1 2`

```
bar 1 2 = \c ->
                [1, 2, c]
```

If what I mean when I say "apply" is hazy, then it may help to know that I really mean [beta reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B2-reduction) from lambda calculus.

Comment: I understand that it takes one argument and returns another function which takes another argument, but how does it calculate anything? So in your case if I had the function `foo a` how is it supposed to do anything with just one argument? I think I need a more detailed explanation as to the process of it working.

Comment: Look at the lambdas. That's what's actually happening. Hang on, im editing cause this is too small

Comment: @user1831442 There you are

Comment: Hmmm, so are you saying that for `foo a b = a + b` `(foo 4) 5` just plugs in `4` so we get `4 + b`? What I'm getting from your example is that `bar` is just plugging stuff in. Gah, currying seems like such a simple concept to understand, why am I having so much trouble understanding it?!

Comment: Yeah thats it! It's basically boils down to substitution. And don't worry everyone who learns Haskell hits stuff like this :)

Comment: Okay, so what if I had three parameters then? `foo a b c = a + b + c`. Would this be equal to `((foo a) b) c`? And thanks four your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26597/discussion-between-jozefg-and-user1831442)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your background, you may find this paper enlightening: **[How to Make a Fast Curry: Push/Enter vs Eval Apply](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/eval-apply/index.htm)**. While it's true that multi-argument functions can be understood as functions which bind a single parameter and return another function: `max = (\a -> (\b -> if a > b then a else b))`, the actual implementation is quite a bit more efficient.

If the compiler knows statically that `max` requires two arguments, the compiler will always translate `max 4 5` by pushing the two arguments on the stack (or in registers) and then invoking `max`. This is essentially the same as how a C compiler would translate `max(4, 5)`.

On the other hand, if for instance `max` is an argument to a higher-order function, the compiler may not know statically how many arguments `max` takes. Perhaps in one instance it takes three, so `max 4 5` is a partial application, or perhaps in another it takes only one and `max 4` generates a new function to which `5` is applied. The paper discusses the two common approaches to handling the case where the arity isn't known statically.

Answer (score 1):

You probably got your answer already, but just to reiterate:

If we have

```
add x y = x + y
```

then we can say the following:

```
add = \ x y -> x + y
add 3 = \ y -> 3 + y
add 3 5 = 3 + 5 = 8
```

You ask "how can `max 3` calculate anything?", and the answer is "it can't". It just gives you another *function*. This function can do something when you call it, but you don't "get an answer" as such until *all* the arguments have been supplied. Until then, you just get functions.

Most of the time, this is just a useful syntactic shortcut. For example, you can write

```
uppercase :: String -> String
uppercase = map toUpper
```

instead of having to say

```
uppercase xs = map toUpper xs
```

Notice that if `map` had its arguments the other way around, we wouldn't be able to do this (you can only curry away the *last* argument, not the _first), so it can be important to think about which order you define your functions' arguments.

---

I say "most of the time" because this is more than syntax sugar. There are several places in the language where you can handle functions with different numbers of arguments *polymorphically* because of currying. Every function either returns an answer, or another function. If you think of it like a linked list (which either contains the next item of data or the end-of-list marker), you can see how this lets you recursively process functions.

So what the heck do I mean by that? Well, for example, QuickCheck can test functions with *any* number of arguments (provided there's a way to auto-generate test data for each argument). This is possible because function types are curried. Every function either returns another function, or a result. If you think about it like a linked list, you can imagine QuickCheck recursively iterating over the function until no more arguments are left.

The following code snippet may or may not explain the idea:

```
class Arbitrary a where
  autogenerate :: RandomGenerator -> a

instance Arbitrary Int
instance Arbitrary Char
...

class Testable t where
  test t :: RandomGenerator -> Bool

instance Testable Bool where
  test rnd b = b

instance (Arbitrary a, Testable t) => Testable (a -> t) where
  test rnd f = test $ f (autogenerate rnd)
```

If we have a function `foo :: Int -> Int -> Bool`, then this is `Testable`. Why? Well, `Bool` is testable, therefore so is `Int -> Bool`, and therefore so is `Int -> (Int -> Bool)`.

By contrast, each size of tuple is a different size, so you have to write separate functions (or instances) for each and every size of tuple. You can't recursively process tuples, because they don't have a recursive structure.

Answer (score 0):

To relate to your own example...

Suppose that you want a function that gives the maximum of 4 and the functions argument. You could implement it like this:

```
max4 :: Integer -> Integer
max4 x = max 4 x
```

What `max 4` does is just to return the function `max4` created on the fly.